# Doing a commit togehter with all the submodules

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to make a commit which recursively or automatically does commits to the submodules as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `git submodule for each git commit; git commit` help?

Comment: If it's an answer, then *Does "this" help?* is not necessary. If it's a comment, post a comment.

Comment: Not my fault. Someone converted my comment to an answer.